# Checking and unchecking of a checkbox using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Checking and unchecking of a checkbox using Selenium WebDriver.

I am using the [page object pattern](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/), so my code appears this way.

```
SelectCheckBox("Check");  OR  SelectCheckBox("Uncheck");

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "payment_sameasdeliveryaddress")]
public IWebElement checkbox_Address = null;

public void SetCheckBox(string value)
{
    //Console.Write("checkbox state: " + checkbox_Address.Selected);
    if (value.ToLower().Equals("uncheck") && checkbox_Address.Selected)
    {
        checkbox_Address.Click();
    }
    else if (value.ToLower().Equals("check") && !checkbox_Address.Selected)
    {
        checkbox_Address.Click();
    }
```

Comment: That is a horrible function! What happens if you call this as `SelectCheckBox("uncheck")`, with lower-case u?

Comment: How about making `value` a Boolean?

Answer (score 1):

It has been years since I wrote any .NET, so the below may not even compile! But hopefully you get the idea.

```
// The individual elements should be declared private
private IWebElement payment_sameasdeliveryaddress;
// If you name it same as the source element
// ID, PageFactory will find it for you

// flag = true, means you want it checked
public void SelectCheckBox(Boolean check)
{
    if (!check && payment_sameasdeliveryaddress.Selected) {
        payment_sameasdeliveryaddress.Click();
    }
    else if (check && !payment_sameasdeliveryaddress.Selected) {
        payment_sameasdeliveryaddress.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
// flag = true, means you want it checked
public void SelectCheckBox(Boolean check)
{
    if (check ^ payment_sameasdeliveryaddress.Selected) {
        payment_sameasdeliveryaddress.Click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of checking a checkbox is checked or not by using the isSelected() method with an element. For example:

```
if(getCheckBox().isSelected()){
    getCheckBox.click();
}

public WebElement getCheckBox(){
    return driver.findElement(termsCheck);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the snippet that's just implemented in the current project using Selenium WebDriver 3.9.1 and [TestNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestNG) 6.14.

```
// Returns boolean value based on whether check-box is selected or not
Boolean chkBx1Sel = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath)).isSelected();
```

Case 1: Check a check-box

```
if(dataValofChkBx != null && dataValofChkBx.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
{
   if(chkBx1Sel.toString() == "false")  //i.e., checkbox is not already checked
   {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(POP2GUIConstants.ggsnFwlfUpdChkBx)).click();
    }
}
```

---

Case 2: Uncheck a check-box

```
if(dataValofChkBx != null && dataValofChkBx.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
{
   if(chkBx1Sel.toString() == "true")  // I.e., checkbox is already checked
   {
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(POP2GUIConstants.ggsnFwlfUpdChkBx)).click();
    }
}
```